# Heroku can't install cli plugins

Tags: git, heroku, plugins, heroku-toolbelt

Everytime I try to install a plugin to the cli (heroku-git in this case), Heroku install the toolbelt v4 and says done but doesn't install the plugin.

I simply run

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-git
```

What i get as an answer is this

```
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done
```

If i try to list plugin with `heroku plugins` it says i dont have any plugins installed.

Another weird thing is if I try to run `heroku git:remote` it says this

```
error loading plugin commands
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done
No such file or directory - "C:/Users/Propri?taire/.heroku/heroku-cli.exe"   plugins
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:56:in ``'  
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:56:in `plugins'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:63:in `is_plugin_installed?' 
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:89:in `install'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/git.rb:48:in `remote'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:212:in `run'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'
" !    Heroku client internal error."
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
" !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com"
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
" !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new"
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
""
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
"    Error:       No such file or directory -     \"C:/Users/Propri\x82taire/.heroku
/heroku-cli.exe\" plugins (Errno::ENOENT)"
#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
"    Command:     heroku git:remote"
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
"    Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.37.1 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3"
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
"\n"
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
"    More information in C:/Users/Propri\x82taire/.heroku/error.log"
#<Encoding:IBM775>
"\n"
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:441:in `join': incompatible
character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and IBM775 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:441:in `format_
error'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:450:in `styled_
error'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:39:in `rescue in st
art'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:19:in `start'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I could finally install the plugin would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-git
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... !    Heroku client internal error.
```

and just run

```
gem install heroku

 !    The `heroku` gem has been deprecated and replaced with the Heroku Toolbelt.
 !    Download and install from: https://toolbelt.heroku.com
 !    For API access, see: https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb
```

After that

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-git
heroku-cli: Installing Toolbelt v4... done
```

successful installed.

p.s. sry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably the non-ascii username. This is a bug in the CLI though.